# Cutting one Shapefile with another?

Tags: shapefile, clip

I have one ESRI Shapefile as a map with many objects in it.

I have another ESRI Shapefile only with borders in it. This shapefile is bigger in size (covering a bigger area) with many border lines. The border lines form many mosaic pieces (tiles).

How can I cut a part out of the map shapefile with the border shapefile as one mosaic piece?

Where is the answer described in the Manual (en or dt) or in the answer to another question?

Comment: in what software and version?

Comment: I Don't think I really understood your question. But I believe you need or a Clip or an intersection.

Comment: If you are using ArcInfo 9.0 then you can use the erase function, which is not available in ArcView.

Answer (score 18):

you can use ogr2ogr if you want:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc polygonforclipping.shp out.shp in.shp
```

*
* *

> -clipsrc [xmin ymin xmax ymax]|WKT|datasource|spat_extent:
>       (starting with GDAL 1.7.0) clip geometries to the specified bounding box (expressed in source SRS), WKT geometry (POLYGON or
>   MULTIPOLYGON), from a datasource or to the spatial extent of the -spat
>   option if you use the spat_extent keyword. When specifying a
>   datasource, you will generally want to use it in combination of the
>   -clipsrclayer, -clipsrcwhere or -clipsrcsql options

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using ArcMap, I think what you want is the **Clip tool**. With it, you can use the border shape files to "cut" through and divide the other shape file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using ArcGIS 10 then you can use the Clip Analysis.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Clip%20(Analysis)

QGIS has the same tool as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using ArcGIS 10.1

**Intersect (Analysis)**
Desktop » Geoprocessing » Tool reference » Analysis toolbox
License Level:Advanced

*"Computes a geometric intersection of the input features. Features or portions of features which overlap in all layers and/or feature classes will be written to the output feature class."*

[image]

Source:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000