# Deleting layer which is overlapping in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, overlapping-features

I had merged two shapefiles.

How to delete a shapefiles which is I give a red sign?

It's like overlapping another shapefiles so I got trouble when I colouring them.

[image]

Comment: You don't have extra shapefiles, you have overlapping data within your layer.  You need to edit the layer, select your unwanted feature, and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is how you can clip one polygon to the shape of another...  if you are, there are a lot of tutorials on how to do that.  Here's one to get you started:

[Cutting one Shapefile with another?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33226/how-to-cut-one-esri-shapefile-with-another-esri-shapefile)

If you just want to delete your "null" values, (the unnamed Shapefile you circled), you can do that using "Select by attributes" - when you select the feature that has the "null" name, you should be able to delete it in editing mode.

I should mention that it would be very helpful to save another copy of your merged file before you try any of the things I mention above, they will all be considered "destructive" edits.